# Позвонить из своей программы

Tags: android

Как позвонить из своей программы на обычный сотовый телефон?

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

В `AndroidManifest.xml` добавьте разрешение `CALL_PHONE`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО! РАБОТАЕТ!